# Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-6051327

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

when I run a java file in android studio, this error happens:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-6051327.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.0.0-6051327/aapt2-4.0.0-6051327.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :objects
```

to give some information, 
build.gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Tue Jun 16 10:43:56 IRDT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

I have tried [Gradle Sync Failed: could not find com.android.tools.build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642157/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-com-android-tools-build), but the problem remains. android studion 4.0. I am new to android.
any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: tnx, but the problem was solved after putting google() in dependencies{}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add `google()` dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google() // this one is missing in your code
      jcenter()
  }
}
```

and use `implementation` instead of `compile` as it was deprecated.

Comment: tnx, after i did that, the problem solved. even i removed google() again but it is still ok. is it normal?

Comment: it might be cached.

Comment: aha, tnx a lot for your respond

Comment: jcenter() > mavenCentral()