# Could not find aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-6051327)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, aapt

I installed android studio on a new device and stared a new project from android studio templates. but when I want to run the application on a device, the build process fails with this message:

> Could not find aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-6051327).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.0.0-6051327/aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-linux.jar

here's my android studio details:

```
Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.3.0-62-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

here's my gradle files:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    ext.realm_version = '5.10.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.queuewatcher"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

I've seen the similar questions and non of them helped, two most related posts are  [Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.0-6051327](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402471/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt24-0-0-6051327) and [Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0) that as you could see in files that I provided can't fix my problem because the solutions were already implemented.

**EDIT:
when I click on the link a jar file downloads on the browser so it's not an internet connection problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was downgrading android studio to 3.6.1. in order to make this work I needed to downgrade the gradle too. so I downgraded it to 5.6.4. so my gradle-wrapper.properties looks like this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

and then I down graded the gradle plugin:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    ext.realm_version = '6.0.2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**NOTE:

please note that it's just a work-around and I couldn't find a decent reason and therefore a decent solution for this!